# AngularJS - 'Please select an item from the list" - Where is that coming from?

Tags: angularjs

I am baffled. In my form, via the submit button having the attribute:

**ng-disabled="templateForm.$invalid"**

and my select being **required**

I am getting an undesired popup asking **"Please Select an Item from the List"**.

I searched the whole application and as near as I am sure I have no remote references.

Does anyone know where this is coming from and how can I stop/override/disable it?

Thanks.

**With Galdo's Help:**

```
  <form id="addForm" ng-submit="doSomething()" name="templateForm" novalidate>
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the novalidate tag to your form like this

```
<form novalidate>
```

This will prevent the browser from doing his own validation of the form using the required attribute.

Comment: Thank you for this. I thought I was going crazy! Just out of curiosity though, is this form validation part of Chrome. I could not find this the sumoselect CSS or JS

Comment: It is part of the browser (not only chrome). novalidate is an attribute added in html5 to prevent automatic form validation done by the different browsers. See this for more details : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

Answer (score 0):

when it's associated to the 'Submit' Button use formnovalidate